# How to get index of an element on given predicate in RethinkDB

Tags: c#, rethinkdb

Hello i have a `table` where i want to get all `documents` after a given document.

The problem is i have not seen a `skipwhile` functionality ,you giving a `predicate`.
So i have to resort to first finding the index of my given element.How is that achieveable?

**Ex:** Given the documents `{"a":1 }`,`{"b":2}`,`{"a":33}`,`{"c":44}`,`{"d":33}` i want to take all the elements after the last `a` so i would like to get: `[ {"c":44},{"d":33}]`

Is this achieveable via the `RethinkDB` driver or i would need to solve this after i take all the table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> So i have to resort to first finding the index of my given element. How
>   is that achieveable?

You can use the [offsetsOf()](https://rethinkdb.com/api/javascript/offsets_of/) function. It returns an array of indices that are matching your searched element. You can get the index of the `{"a":33}` document as follows:

```
r.expr([{"a":1 },{"b":2},{"a":33},{"c":44},{"d":33}])
  .offsetsOf({"a":33}).nth(0)
```

To go further and iterate over the rest of the elements you can use the [r.range()](https://www.rethinkdb.com/api/javascript/range/) function like this:

```
r.expr([{"a":1 },{"b":2},{"a":33},{"c":44},{"d":33}])
    .do(function(docs){
      return docs.offsetsOf({"a":33}).nth(0)
        .do(function(index){
          return r.range(index.add(1), docs.count())
            .map(function(i){
              return docs.nth(i)
            })
        })
    })
```

Answer (score 0):

try something like code below :

```
            List<KeyValuePair<string, int>> input = new List<KeyValuePair<string, int>>() {
                new KeyValuePair<string, int>("a", 1),
                new KeyValuePair<string, int>("b", 2),
                new KeyValuePair<string, int>("a",33),
                new KeyValuePair<string, int>("c",44),
                new KeyValuePair<string, int>("d",33)
            };

            int skipIndex = input.Select((x, i) => new { value = x, index = i }).Where(x => x.value.Key == "a").Last().index;
            List<KeyValuePair<string, int>> results = input.Skip(skipIndex + 1).ToList();
```

Comment: I was looking for an answer using the `RethinkDB`  `REQL`api.I want to perform this query on the database not after i have loaded all the `table` in memory.

Comment: I do not understand your last comment.

Answer (score 0):

I tried to save your problem following the example you gave asking your Question:

> -I've got a Folder with the following files/documents{a.txt,b.txt,c.txt,d.txt,f.txt}
>
> -I want an Array of all files after the -count- (look at the GetFilesAfterFilename function) time occurrence of the name "b.txt"

---

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;

namespace ConsoleApp1
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            DirectoryInfo DirectoryOfDocuments = new DirectoryInfo(Environment.CurrentDirectory+ @"\documents");//Get direcory with your files(Ex: a.txt,b.txt,c.txt,d.txt,..)
            FileInfo[] OldFileInfo = DirectoryOfDocuments.GetFiles();//Get all files out of your directory

            FileInfo[] NewFileInfo = GetFilesAfterFilename(OldFileInfo, 1, "c.txt");

            foreach (FileInfo fi in NewFileInfo)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(fi.ToString());
            }
            Console.Read();
        }

        static FileInfo[] GetFilesAfterFilename(FileInfo[] OriginArray, int count, string FileName) {
            List<FileInfo> NewFileInfo = new List<FileInfo>();
            int FileNameOccurrence = 0;
            foreach (FileInfo fi in OriginArray)
            {
                if (FileNameOccurrence == count){//Add all Files from OriginArray after [count] time occurrence of somewhat file/document
                    NewFileInfo.Add(fi);
                }else if (fi.ToString()==FileName) {
                    FileNameOccurrence++;
                }
            }

            return NewFileInfo.ToArray();
        }
    }
}
```

---

Console output

---

d.txt
f.txt

---